# How to verify if a specific value exists in a set of Key-Value pairs?

Tags: jquery

Given:

```
var dic = {1: 11, 2: 22, 3:22, 4:44, 5:22};
```

How to find out efficiently the number of times `22` has been a value to a key in that set using jQuery?

Comment: `for(var x in dic) if(dic[x] === 22) count++;`

Answer (score 1):

you can loop and count,

```
arr22 = [];
$.each(dic,function(k,v){
  if (v == 22) { arr22[arr22.length] = {k: v} }
})

arr22.length // length
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var dic = {1: 11, 2: 22, 3:22, 4:44, 5:22};

var vals = Object.values(dic); //Gives [11, 22, 22, 44, 22]
```

Then, iterate over the array **vals**

```
var count = 0;

jQuery.each(vals, function(i,v) { if (v === 22) count++; });
```

At the end **count** will have the total occurrence of desired element

**EDIT**

Even the last line of code above can be put into a function:

```
function countElement(ele) {
  var count = 0;
  jQuery.each(vals, function(i,v) { if (v === ele) count++; });
  return count;
}
```

And call it like:

```
countElement(22); //Gives 3
```